# Bash passing string as variable to function

Tags: string, bash, function, variables

Why when I try to pass a string stored in a variable to a bash function, it splits up the string. For example:

```
function PROCESS {
  echo $1               ### This only outputs "THIS" not "THIS IS AN ERROR"
}

ERROR="THIS IS AN ERROR"
PROCESS $ERROR
```

In case this information is of importance, parts of the actual error message are generated from variables. For example, an actual error message might look like

```
ERROR=$YELLOW"REPORT TITLE$RESET can not be left blank!"
```

This would create the following message:

```
ReportA can not be left blank!
```

Where "ReportA" is highlighted yellow

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Typo

Answer (score 1):

Wow ok so I am stupid. The answer was VERY simple...

```
PROCESS "$ERROR"
```

DUH